# Check if values in all n previous rows are greater than the value of current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
    col_name
0      2
1      3
2      1
3      0
4      5
5      4
6      3
7      3
```

that could be created with the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col_name': [2, 3, 1, 0, 5, 4, 3, 3]
    }
)
```

Now, I want to get the rows which have a value less than the values in **all** the `n` previous rows. So, for `n=2` the output is the rows: `2, 3, 6`.

Additionally I don't want to use any for-loops in my code.

Just a trick that comes to my mind is that we can count the number of rows in `n` previous rows having a value less than the current row and then check if the number equals to `n`.

Have you any idea for the code with my trick or in any other ways? and also is there a way to write a similar code except that if we want to check if values in `n` next rows are less than the value of the current row?

Comment: Why is index seven not included in your expected output? Three is less than four.

Comment: I want the value of current row to be less than the values in **all** ```n``` previous rows. So, in index seven the value is equal to the value of index six, not less than it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use `rolling` to calculate the `min` value in `n` previous rows then compare the min value with current row to create a boolean mask

```
df[df['col_name'] < df['col_name'].shift().rolling(2, min_periods=1).min()]
```

---

```
   col_name
2         1
3         0
6         3
```

Comment: Very smart and very clever Shubham :)